# Compute the order of the following elements in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G = \mathbb Z_{84}$. Let $g,h \in G$, with $g = 6, h = 80$. Compute $|g|, |h|$ and $|gh^{-1}|$.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I was trying to figure out how to edit the poorly written question by me.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  how many $6$'s do you have to add together to get a multiple of $84?$.  Since $h$ is so large, it is easier to think about $-4$.  Then what is $h^{-1}$ and hence what is $gh^{-1}$?

Comment: For $\mathbb |h|$, $80\equiv-4(mod 84)$. Then $h^{-1}$ $= 4$. Is this correct?

Comment: @user80979:  yes, that's right.  Then don't forget that your group operation is addition, not multiplication.

Comment: $|gh^{-1}|$ $=|10|$. Now, there is an $\mathbb n \in Z$ such that $ 10^{n}$ $=0$$mod(84)$. Since, $5 * 84 $$= 420$ $\equiv$ 10$(mod84)$$, $|10|=5$

Comment: @user80979:  Did you get $|g|$ and $|h|$?  Yes, there is such.  In usual arithmetic, you would be looking for $n$ such that $10n \equiv 0 \pmod {84}$, so $10n$ needs to be a multiple of $84$

Comment: 42 * 10 is congruent to 0 (mod 84).

Comment: @user80979: that is right.  You might note that it is the LCM of the orders of $6$ and $-4$